# How to get an image stored on google cloud Platform bucket?

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to download the images stored on my Google Cloud bucket and display all the images on my react native app.

I have stored the images on a bucket by encrypting them using my key.

I want to decrypt my images and then display them to the users.

I want the help to react native code to connect with Google Cloud Platform and retrieve my images.

Comment: Is you app have a backend? Have you plan to decrypt the image on the backend?

Comment: I am planning to get only the URL from backend and i would decrypt the image using the key on the frontend.

Comment: I just want to understand. Why are you using your own key? If you put the encryption in your front end, this key is public and your encryption value is void. The only reason is to prevent any read from Google (or agency or someone else) because it's your key and it's not reachable on GCP (but on your app). So, I provide you an answer to your question, but not sure that using your own encryption key is a good idea which generate overwork.

Comment: By my own key, I mean Key provided by google

Answer (score 2):

For reading the files from the bucket, you have to set the bucket publicly accessible. Go to Storage, click on the 3 dots on the right of your bucket line, select Edit Bucket Permission. Then, click on Add Member and add `allUsers` with the role storage object viewer.

Now all your files in the bucket are publicly accessible. The URL of your files will be:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/myBucket/path/to/file
```

Then, decrypt the file on with your key.